# I found these in a CMD file, what does it do?

Tags: cmd, dos

I found these in a CMD file, what does it do?

```
   @echo off 
   if not "%~1"=="p" start /min cmd.exe /c %0 p&exit
   start "" "GTAVLauncher.exe"
   start "" "Launcher.exe"
   timeout /t 120 /nobreak >nul
   taskkill /f /im GTAVLauncher.exe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read and learn yourself:

- `echo`, `if`, `start`, `cmd`, `exit`, `timeout`, `taskkill` in [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- `%~1`, `%0` in [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- `&`, `>` in [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: ty, il happily do that